# ObjectiveC - How to remove same previous UIView before create new

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am creating a view on **UITableView** here is the code

```
UIView *olderLinesView = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1820];

for (UIView* view in [olderLinesView subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
[olderLinesView removeFromSuperview];

UIView *linesView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, -2, 1022, height)];
[linesView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[linesView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[linesView setTag:1820];
[tableView addSubview:linesView];
```

But the problem is if i remove **olderLinesView** before creating **linesView** (same view) the **linesView** is not created at all. And if i don't remove this view before creating it, it redraws the view over and over. I am calling this code again and again so need to remove this view before creating its new instance. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you shure that linesView is nil, or the view is not added to the tableView ?

Comment: It is not being displayed. It suddenly hides, when i checked the object of linesView was not nil it is created but not being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify code as below

```
UIView *olderLinesView = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1820];

for (UIView* view in [tableview subviews]) 
{
      if( [view isKindOfClass:[olderLinesView class]] )
    {
      for (UIView* subview in [view subviews]) 
      {

      [subview removeFromSuperview]; //if you want all views
      }
    }
}
///(OR)

for (UIView* view in [tableview subviews]) 
{
      if( [view isKindOfClass:[olderLinesView class]] )
    {
      for (UIView* subview in [view subviews]) 
      {
      if(subview.tag==1820)
      {

        [subview removeFromSuperview];//if you want remove single view
      }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: I was waiting for the time until you can accept answer :)